# 404 page not found for face-api.js

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, iis, face-detection

I am trying to implement the face-api.js in a simple project hosted on a local IIS 
but I am getting the following issue

[image]

here is my javascript code

```
Promise.all([
faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri('/models')
]).then(start)
```

I added my website on IIS as follow and add a custom domain in the host file and I am browsing the website as follow: *http://facelocal/index.html*

[image]

Also my hierarchy looks like the following

[image]

The response is the following:

[image]

Can anyone help me figure out this issue?

Comment: where are your modals located ? the modals should be in a location accessible by url `http://facelocal/index.html/models/<modalname>`. refer [this](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js#loading-the-models)

Comment: i made a mistake it should have been http://facelocal/models/<modalname>

Comment: check your path carefully. You are linking the incorrect path. That's why it is showing 404 error. What is your path? and Where are your files located?

Comment: Yes it is "facelocal/models/<modalname>", but still not working and the same error occured when i tried to add the application/octet-stream in the staticContent section in the web.config

Comment: Try using https://www.getpostman.com/ to test your links to see if it is a path issue or a code issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is quite clear.

HTTP error `404.3` is a specific error in IIS: [MIME type restriction](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0).

IIS needs to know what content type to respond to static files without extension (like your model files).

Since it's undefined by default, you need to set a MIME type for extension-less static files.

Put the following `web.config` file in your web application's root folder or update the existing one by adding nodes `remove` and `mimeMap` respectively under `configuration/system.webServer/staticContent`.

I don't know what should be your model file MIME type, so assumed it was `text/plain`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <!-- "." means no extension -->
            <!--  to prevent future duplication errors, remove "." mime map in case a higher level configuration is defined somewhere in the web server tree -->
            <remove fileExtension="." />
            <!-- now add the mime map again -->
            <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/plain" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you manage to configure this, those `404.3` errors will not occur again.

---

Related: [Adding Static Content MIME Mappings <mimeMap>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, you saved my day, i was trying to add it that way but my syntax was not correct

Answer (score 0):

the data is HDF5 ,so
Add MIME   => "."  => "application/octet-stream" or  "application/x-hdf"

[image]